# GCM Windows firewall configuration

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, windows-firewall

I am not able to connect to GCM. Exception: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235. I have got firewall exemption for one IP for 'android.googleapis.com'. able to connect, supposedly only when this IP is in use by GCM. Please help me with this. Do I need to get firewall exemption for a set of IPs that google uses? if yes, what are those IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.googleapis.com is a generic url for most apis for android. 
Doesn't have any IP range defined.

You should do domain whitelisting in your firewall for Android push notification to work.